# Split string based on count of comma separated in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, split

Need a SQL Server query. Below is the example

1) 19003 IH-10 West, San Antonio, 78257, TX, United States

In the first example there are four commas in the string. So output should be

```
19003 IH-10 West
```

2) Chevron Pipe Line Company, 4800 Fournace Place, Bellaire, 77401-2324, TX, United States

In the second example there are five commas in the string. So output should be

```
Chevron Pipe Line Company, 4800 Fournace Place
```

If there are four commas, then output should be a substring of main string up to the 1st comma, and if there are five commas, then output should be a substring of main string up to the 2nd comma.

In input, there are only 4 or 5 commas.

I can achieve this requirement by using an UDF. But I need a direct query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how this would perform.  I highly recommend a better way to split out addresses and store as separate fields, there are many address parsing solutions available.

If that is not an option, the following would work but may need altering depending on performance.

```
Drop Table #Temp
Create Table #Temp (Field Varchar(8000))
Insert #Temp Values ('19003 IH-10 West, San Antonio, 78257, TX, United States')
Insert #Temp Values ('Chevron Pipe Line Company, 4800 Fournace Place, Bellaire, 77401-2324, TX, United States')

;With cteFindCommas As
(
Select  CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field)+1)+1)+1)+1) FifthCommaPos,
        CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field)+1)+1)+1) FourthCommaPos,
        CharIndex(',', Field) FirstCommaPos,
        CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field)+1) SecondCommaPos,
        *
    From #Temp
)
Select  Case When FifthCommaPos > 0 Then Substring(Field, 0, SecondCommaPos)
             Else Substring(Field, 0, FirstCommaPos) End String,            
        * 
    From cteFindCommas
```

Comment: This is a very good solution. You don't, however, need to calculate the position of each comma only the string. You only need the 1st 2 position along with a count of the delimiters. Note my solution.

Comment: The comma count is pretty neat.  I dont have time to test but I wonder if it would make a performance difference using replace vs. multiple charindexes and if replace is slower in this instance at what point might it tip the other way.

Comment: I added a performance test. It looks like what you put together was faster by ~15%. Bravo.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it (note the comments in my code):

```
-- sample data
declare @sometable table (someid int identity, someAddress varchar(200));
insert @sometable (someAddress) 
values ('19003 IH-10 West, San Antonio, 78257, TX, United States'),
       ('Chevron Pipe Line Company, 4800 Fournace Place, Bellaire, 77401-2324, TX, US');

-- solution
select 
  someid,
  someAddress,
  newAddress = case commaCount when 4 then C4 when 5 then C5 end -- conditions for 4 or 5 commas only
from
(
  select 
    someid,
    someAddress,
    commaCount = len(v.a) - len(replace(v.a,',','')), -- calculate the number of commas
    C4 = substring(v.a, 1, charindex(',', v.a)-1), -- grab everything up to the 1st comma
    C5 = substring(v.a, 1, charindex(',', v.a, charindex(',', v.a)+1)-1) -- everything up to 2nd comma
  from @sometable t
    cross apply (values (t.someAddress)) v(a)   -- how I avoid repeated references to t.SomeAddress
) formatStrings;
```

**Results**

```
someid  someAddress                                              newAddress
------- -------------------------------------------------------  ----------------------------------------------
1       19003 IH-10 West, San Antonio, 78257, TX, United States  19003 IH-10 West
2       Chevron Pipe Line Company, 4800 Fournace Place...        Chevron Pipe Line Company, 4800 Fournace Place
```

**UPDATE - ADDING PERFORMANCE TEST**

Below is a test harness I put together; note my comments.

**Sample data**

```
-- #1: Create Sample Data
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @rows int = 100000;
if object_id('tempdb..#base') is not null drop table #base;
if object_id('tempdb..#address') is not null drop table #address;

-- grabbed 50 random addresses from here: https://www.randomlists.com/random-addresses
-- manually added the first comma (between street address and city)
select 
  someId      = identity(int,1,1),
  someAddress = stuff(addr,patindex('%'+replicate('[0-9]',5)+'%',addr),0,',')
into #base from (values
('886 Hartford Ave., Gwynn Oak, MD 21207'),
('322 Wakehurst St., Deerfield, IL 60015'),
('62 South Oak Valley St., Lorain, OH 44052'),
('72 53rd St., New Bern, NC 28560'),
('569 Swanson Ave., Snellville, GA 30039'),
('15 Walnut St., New Bern, NC 28560'),
('94 Kingston St., North Royalton, OH 44133'),
('77 Rock Creek St., Ocean Springs, MS 39564'),
('688 S. Bellevue St., Mableton, GA 30126'),
('61 Queen Rd., Potomac, MD 20854'),
('72 Jockey Hollow Drive, Elgin, IL 60120'),
('777 School St., Clarksville, TN 37040'),
('50 North 1st Street, Mount Prospect, IL 60056'),
('8004 Valley Drive, Long Beach, NY 11561'),
('8569 Franklin Court, Lakeland, FL 33801'),
('837 Buckingham St., Newnan, GA 30263'),
('46 Birch Hill St., Helena, MT 59601'),
('617 E. Brookside Drive, Jersey City, NJ 07302'),
('8133 Valley View St., Clearwater, FL 33756'),
('42 South Ave., Greensburg, PA 15601'),
('8782 Oak Meadow St., Helotes, TX 78023'),
('35 Valley Farms Ave., Racine, WI 53402'),
('7613 Cobblestone Road, Orlando, FL 32806'),
('27 Broad Lane, Kaukauna, WI 54130'),
('9213 Corona Dr., Rockville, MD 20850'),
('7390 W. Bay Court, Mason, OH 45040'),
('561 W. St Louis Ave., Silver Spring, MD 20901'),
('7447 Evergreen Ave., Rocky Mount, NC 27804'),
('24 NW. Pilgrim Road, Sun Prairie, WI 53590'),
('846 E. Hall St., Lake Villa, IL 60046'),
('919 Green Hill Street, New Orleans, LA 70115'),
('532 Newbridge Lane, Hanover, PA 17331'),
('3 E. Rose Rd., Waukegan, IL 60085'),
('15 South Euclid Rd., Springfield Gardens, NY 11413'),
('453 Mulberry Ave., Parlin, NJ 08859'),
('8128 New Saddle Court, Fullerton, CA 92831'),
('9143 Lafayette Ave., Jackson Heights, NY 11372'),
('481 Edgewater St., Dacula, GA 30019'),
('8243 Hilltop St., Camp Hill, PA 17011'),
('70 Lookout St., Marlborough, MA 01752'),
('9370 South Shirley Drive, King Of Prussia, PA 19406'),
('8071 Plymouth Road, Huntersville, NC 28078'),
('593 Charles St., Buckeye, AZ 85326'),
('9092 Atlantic Ave., Yuma, AZ 85365'),
('81 Longbranch Road, Ontario, CA 91762'),
('868 Garfield St., New Lenox, IL 60451'),
('8333 Kirkland Rd., Plainview, NY 11803'),
('9714 Prospect Ave., Monroe Township, NJ 08831'),
('7 N. Atlantic Ave., Reidsville, NC 27320'),
('9283 Cherry Lane, Waukegan, IL 60085')) a(addr);

-- index to support large sample data requests:
create unique clustered index uq_cl_base on #base(someid);

-- Create randomized addresses: up to 6,250,000 dummy rows (50^4)
with r(x) as (select top(@rows/50) 1 from #base a, #base b, #base c, #base d),
base(Field) as
(
  select Field  =
    max(
      case itemNumber when 1 then substring(item,charindex(' ',item)+1, len(item)+1) end+
        case abs(checksum(newid())%10)
        when 0 then ', Unit '+ cast(abs(checksum(newid())%100)+1 as varchar(3))
        when 1 then ', Suite '+ cast(abs(checksum(newid())%100)+1 as varchar(3))
        when 2 then ', Penthouse' else '' end)+','+
    max(case ItemNumber when 2 then item end)+','+
    max(case ItemNumber when 3 then left(item,3)+', ' end)+
    max(case ItemNumber when 4 then item end)+', United States'
  from #base t
  cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.someAddress,',')
  group by t.someId
)
select addressId = identity(int,1,1),
       field     =
         left(cast(abs(checksum(newid())%10000)+1 as varchar(5)), 
           case checksum(newid())%3 when 4 then 4 when 1 then 1 else 3 end)+' '+b.Field
into #address
from base b
cross join r
order by newid();
go
```

**Performance Test**

```
set nocount on;
print 'solution 1'+char(10)+replicate('-',50);
go
declare @st datetime = getdate(), @field varchar(100);
  ;With cteFindCommas As
  (
  Select  CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field)+1)+1)+1)+1) FifthCommaPos,
          CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field)+1)+1)+1) FourthCommaPos,
          CharIndex(',', Field) FirstCommaPos,
          CharIndex(',', Field, CharIndex(',', Field)+1) SecondCommaPos, *
  From #Address
  )
  select @field = case when FifthCommaPos > 0 Then Substring(Field, 0, SecondCommaPos)
                  else Substring(Field, 0, FirstCommaPos) end
  From cteFindCommas;
print datediff(ms,@st,getdate());
go 5

print 'solution 2'+char(10)+replicate('-',50);
go
declare @st datetime = getdate(), @field varchar(100);
  select @field = case commaCount when 4 then C4 when 5 then C5 end -- conditions for 4 or 5 commas only
  from
  (
    select
      addressId,
      field,
      commaCount = len(v.a) - len(replace(v.a,',','')), -- calculate the number of commas
      C4 = substring(v.a, 1, charindex(',', v.a)-1), -- grab everything up to the 1st comma
      C5 = substring(v.a, 1, charindex(',', v.a, charindex(',', v.a)+1)-1) -- everything up to 2nd comma
    from #address t cross apply (values (t.field)) v(a)
  ) formatStrings;
print datediff(ms,@st,getdate());
go 5
```

**Results (100,000 row test)**

```
solution 1
--------------------------------------------------
Beginning execution loop
133
133
130
126
126
Batch execution completed 5 times.

solution 2
--------------------------------------------------
Beginning execution loop
156
160
156
157
153
Batch execution completed 5 times.
```

***It looks like Joe C's solution (solution #1) was faster.***